# Lightest single page scraper

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

There is some website that publishes some everchanging data. There is no api but I need to access that value programmatically in js. This is a common problem for me.

I am writing a simple js script(HTML/js) [hackyAPI](https://github.com/praneethmendu/hackyAPI/blob/master/hack.html), HTML/js or client side is enough for any manipulations I want to do on the data.

But the problem is XMLHttpRequest and cross server permissions. I do not want to introduce server elements just for this. Is there is a workaround considering I just want a typical html respone ?

Comment: There is no avoiding the server element here. Browsers are *extremely* restrictive.

Comment: you can proxy requests via your server to overcome the CORS resource protection mechanism - there is no other way to bypass resource protection other than make requests from server to server - this will result in your server using much more bandwidth than you probably want, consider some intelligent caching if you see this as an issue

Answer (score 1):

CORS restrictions are enforced by browsers explicitly to prevent this kind of script (as well as more malicious XSS scripts); whoever is running that site is providing those resources (and paying to serve them up), so unless they're offering a public API it's not really fair to use that data in the way you seem to be trying to do. In this particular case it seems to be directly in conflict with the site's terms of service.